# What is that feeling when you feel peaceful but empty?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call it when you feel peaceful but seemingly empty, it's really weird to experience. You know those days when you have those thoughts that are empty but peaceful and really, really deep, for example, a few of the thoughts I've had while feeling this way are: "What if nothing ever matters and everything is just an illusion." "If life on earth is just a pitstop how come some people have more than one?" and other things like feeling warm and fuzzy but at the same time cold and hard, or thinking back on memories wondering if any of them ever mattered then sometimes missing them, and just like reflecting on everything within minutes of thinking about it???

(Note: I'm only 13 so if you have a response please make it easier for me to understand thank you!)

Comment: This is just too vague! What on earth are we to understand by "empty" thoughts here, for example?

Comment: [*The **Sophist**, Gorgias, advanced the **skeptical-nihilist thesis** that nothing exists; and, if something did exist, it could not be known; and, if it could be known, it could not be communicated.*](https://www.britannica.com/topic/skepticism)

Comment: I would call anxious thoughts unsettling, and a recipe for depression.

Comment: Those are [existentialist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existentialism) thoughts. "...philosophical inquiry that explores the problem of human existence and centers on the lived experience of the thinking, feeling, acting individual."

Comment: An excellent question, and well-written!  I've on several occasions had this sensation, but I cannot think of a word to describe it.

Comment: I know what you are talking about. It's not like thinking that life is an illusion is comforting, but rather that you have the feeling of being outside of yourself, being able to consider things in a timeless sort of state. It is in those moments that I feel like my soul is disassociated from my body, that it is slipping free. You feel at once forever young and forever old. There is no one word for it, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

'**Removed**' defined as: separate or remote in space, time, or character.

Etymology removed (v.)
Early 14c., "move, take away, dismiss," from Old French removoir "move, stir; leave, depart; take away," from Latin removere "move back or away, take away, put out of view, subtract," from re- "back, away" (see re-) + movere "to move" (from PIE root *meue- "to push away"). Related: Removed; removing ([www.etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com) › word › remove (https://www.etymonline.com/word/remove)

In use: I often feel **removed** from everything going on around me (https://ludwig.guru/s/i+feel+removed).

Answer (score 0):

**Disillusioned**

adjective

having lost one's ideals, illusions, or false ideas about someone or something; disenchanted

Incidentally, ***disenchanted*** would also work in this case.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/disillusioned

Comment: doesn't sound very peaceful to me

Answer (score 0):

It’s great to see others have the same feelings and questions that I go through every day. I call it *numb peace*.

Why? Easy. For me, I have been numb so long, and haven’t had the best life even now, but I’ve always carried great anxiety through my situations and only believed in this quote “everything happens for a reason”. This quote has always been able to bring me back into reality where I only seek self control. Numb peace, which I made up whole thinking of your question, is the peace you feel after mastering self control. It may also be that your mindset has awaken, and you spirit is more settled then usual, making you feel confused as to why, there is so much peace yet still a feeling of emptiness well.

In order to not be empty, someone has to fill the void, basically you no longer need someone to help you fill this void, but yourself. Even then, we ourselves are not enough for company, that sense of emptiness and peace, is that you’re missing something. Just lay down, don’t stress and recap through your heart, what it is that you need.